# Which Column was selected when DoubleClick a Row of a ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

First of all, I'm not talking about clicking the column header.  I'm talking about the item in a selected row.
I have a ListView and wanting to double click the `username` column in a selected row and copy username to clipboard.
If I double click the `password` column of a selected row, copy the password to clipboard.

Obviously we can tell what row is selected, but I can't figure out how to capture what column was double clicked within that row.
Is that possible?

People want code so here ya go, keep in mind only single row can be selected so yes, 0 will work:

```
ListViewItem lvi = this.contentListView.SelectedItems[0];
string pass = lvi.SubItems[5].Text;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ListView [HitTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.hittest) method. It returns a [ListViewHitTestInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewhittestinfo) object.
Its [SubItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewhittestinfo.subitem) property gives you the `ListViewSubItem` object clicked:

The corresponding `ColumnHeader` object can be identified using the [ListViewItem.SubItems.IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitemcollection.indexof) method. Both the `ListViewItem` and `SubItem` are referenced in the `ListViewHitTestInfo` object.

```
private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hitInfo = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);
    if (hitInfo.SubItem == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(hitInfo.SubItem.Text)) return;

    int subItemIndex = hitInfo.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(hitInfo.SubItem);
    var column = listView1.Columns[subItemIndex];

    // Do whatever you need to do with the SubItem text
    string result = ProcessSubItemText(hitInfo.SubItem.Text, column);
    Clipboard.SetText(result, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
}
```

Comment: So close..   Yea that gives the data, but how do I get the column name?   I need that because the password isn't clear text, it's encrypted, then base64.   Of course I can attempt to reverse that, which will fail if not an encrypted password. I could even grab the item.text then walk through, find the row, then walk the column over to find which column was selected, but Id like to be a bit cleaner than that.

Comment: hitInfo.SubItem.Name seems to always be empty.

Comment: I found a work around..                  ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(accountName, 0);
                ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
                lvsi.Name = "Username";
                lvsi.Text = userName;
                item.SubItems.Add(lvsi);

Comment: See the edit. You can use the Item provided by the HitTest.