# How can I add context menu on listview item right click with the mouse?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to be able to click select item in the list view control and than to make right click with the mouse and show something.

This is the costum control I created :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Search_Text_In_Files
{
    public partial class ListViewCostumControl : UserControl
    {
        public static ListViewControl lvnf;

        public ListViewCostumControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lvnf = new ListViewControl();
            lvnf.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            lvnf.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            lvnf.View = View.Details;
            lvnf.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lvnf.SuspendLayout();
            lvnf.LabelEdit = true;
            lvnf.HeaderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
            lvnf.Columns.Add("", 984, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            //lvnf.Columns.Add("Subject", 200);
            //lvnf.Columns.Add("Date", 300);
            lvnf.Sorting = SortOrder.None;
            //lvnf.ColumnClick += lvnf_ColumnClick;
            //lvnf.Click += lvnf_Click;
            //lvnf.SelectedIndexChanged += lvnf_SelectedIndexChanged;
            this.Controls.Add(lvnf);
            lvnf.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        public class ListViewControl : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
        {
            public ListViewControl()
            {
                //Activate double buffering
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

                //Enable the OnNotifyMessage event so we get a chance to filter out 
                // Windows messages before they get to the form's WndProc
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
            }

            protected override void OnNotifyMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                //Filter out the WM_ERASEBKGND message
                if (m.Msg != 0x14)
                {
                    base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ListViewNFTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Than in Form1 :

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.MouseClick += Lvnf_MouseClick;
```

And in the event :

```
private void Lvnf_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                var focusedItem = ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.FocusedItem;
                if (focusedItem != null && focusedItem.Bounds.Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
                }
            }
        }
```

but it's not showing nothing when making a right click with the mouse on selected item in the list view.

Comment: Why do you have `public static ListViewControl lvnf;` there? So you allegedly can *access it from the outside*? Or is this Control (whatever that is) meant to be the same exact object in all instance of your UserControl (so all instances of the UserControl will show the same content)? -- A ListView has a `HitTest` that lets you determine which ListViewItems or ListViewSubItems has been clicked or selected. E.g., [How to get the selected SubItem index in a Listview and highlight it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65860374/7444103)

Comment: Or [Which Column was selected when DoubleClick a Row of a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61779401/7444103)

Comment: Have you tried `lvnf.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1` without `Lvnf_MouseClick`?

Comment: Use MouseDown !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to declare context menu and at least one item.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStrip1;
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem toolStripMenuItem1;
```

Next to you need to create objects and assign them to your listView.

```
this.contextMenuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip(this.components);
this.contextMenuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
this.toolStripMenuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
this.toolStripMenuItem1});
this.contextMenuStrip1.Name = "contextMenuStrip1";
this.contextMenuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);

lvnf.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
```

Just look what designer does when you add the context menu.
You do not need to handle mouse events as it is done by context menu automatically. Instead use menu/item events.

If you need context menu to appear only on listView item/items selected, then you can handle opening event and suppress menu if no items selected.

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (lvnf.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```